# Flutter - Image taking the whole screen width

Tags: flutter, dart

In a Detail page, I'd like an image to take the whole width available, on the very top. This is my code:

```java
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[

          Container(
           child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Image.asset(
                  this.imageLink,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
     ),
);
```

The problème is : with the emulator, the result is exactly what I want :

[image]

But when I launch the app on a real phone (Galaxy S8 Plus) there are some paddings (top, left and right) and the image doesn't fit the screen width.

Which means that something is not correct in the way I tried to do it with the code.

Where could be the problem ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the reason being original `width` of image is equal or more than the width of emulator and which is less than your Samsung S8+ width, you need to use

```
Image.asset(
  this.linkImage,
  width: double.infinity,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
),
```

Comment: I understand. So that's why I needed to add both `width: double.infinity` and `fit: BoxFit.cover`

Comment: Yes, you need both of them to make sure your image is loaded in full width in all devices not just S8+, and you can get rid of your `Container` which is parent of your `Image.asset`

Answer (score 4):

You will have use expanded widget for that  or you can use

```
 height: double.infinity,
    width: double.infinity,
```

or

```
new Image.asset('assets/images/umbrella.png',
          width: size.width,
          height: size.height,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use

fit: BoxFit.cover,